# Subtract/Add existing values if contents of one dataframe is present in another using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here are 2 dataframes

df1:

```
Index Number Name  Amount
  0    123   John   31
  1    124   Alle   33
  2    312   Amy    33
  3    314   Holly  35
```

df2:

```
Index Number Name  Amount
  0    312   Amy    13
  1    124   Alle   35
  2    317   Jack   53
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this

result_df:

```
Index Number Name  Amount  Curr_amount
  0    123   John   31       31
  1    124   Alle   33       68
  2    312   Amy    33       46
  3    314   Holly  35       35
  4    317   Jack            53
```

I have tried using pandas *isin* but it only says if the *Number* column was present or no in boolean. Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with outer join and then add [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) (or 
[`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) if necessary):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Number','Name'], how='outer', suffixes=('','_curr'))
df['Amount_curr'] = df['Amount_curr'].add(df['Amount'], fill_value=0)
print (df)
   Number   Name  Amount  Amount_curr
0     123   John    31.0         31.0
1     124   Alle    33.0         68.0
2     312    Amy    33.0         46.0
3     314  Holly    35.0         35.0
4     317   Jack     NaN         53.0
```